# Single word color in mathematica

Tags: graphics, miktex, graphs, font-encodings, wolfram-mathematica

When we give color to a word in latext, e.g., if we need red color to a word "Moon", we write \textcolor{red}{Moon}. How we can do same in a mathematica when we are writing text inside a graph and we need some single word red?

Comment: This is off topic here you should ask on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about mathematica, not tex